# Python multiprocessing easy way to implement a simple counter?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Hey everyone, I am using multiprocessing in python now. and I am just wondering whether there exists some sort of simple counter variable that each process when they are done processing some task could just increment ( kind of like how much work done in total).

I looked up the API for Value, don't think it's mutable.

Answer (score 27):

`Value` is indeed mutable; you specify the datatype you want from the `ctypes` module and then it can be mutated.  Here's a complete, working script that demonstrates this:

```
from time import sleep
from ctypes import c_int
from multiprocessing import Value, Lock, Process

counter = Value(c_int)  # defaults to 0
counter_lock = Lock()
def increment():
    with counter_lock:
        counter.value += 1

def do_something():
    print("I'm a separate process!")
    increment()

Process(target=do_something).start()
sleep(1)
print counter.value   # prints 1, because Value is shared and mutable
```

EDIT: Luper correctly points out in a comment below that `Value` values are locked by default.  This is correct in the sense that even if an assignment consists of multiple operations (such as assigning a string which might be many characters) then this assignment is atomic.  However, when incrementing a counter you'll still need an external lock as provided in my example, because incrementing loads the current value and then increments it and then assigns the result back to the `Value`.

So without an external lock, you might run into the following circumstance:

- Process 1 reads (atomically) the current value of the counter, then increments it
- before Process 1 can assign the incremented counter back to the `Value`, a context switch occurrs
- Process 2 reads (atomically) the current (unincremented) value of the counter, increments it, and assigns the incremented result (atomically) back to `Value`
- Process 1 assigns its incremented value (atomically), blowing away the increment performed by Process 2

Comment: Value accesses are protected by a Lock by default.

Comment: You need "from __future__ import with_statement" here, no?

Comment: @Edward: You do need the future import if you're using Python 2.5, I was using Python 2.6 when I wrote that code, so it was unnecessary.

Comment: Given that Lock is used, why does Value have to be used? Why can't a simple `int` be used instead?

Comment: @A-B-B: Because the `Value` is what allows us to share the same `int` across processes.  The invocation of `do_something` which calls `increment` is happening in a separate process, so if our value was a simple int, it wouldn't be incremented in the original parent process.