# How to increment a shared counter from multiple processes?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am having troubles with the `multiprocessing` module. I am using a `Pool` of workers with its `map` method to concurrently analyze lots of files. Each time a file has been processed I would like to have a counter updated so that I can keep track of how many files remains to be processed. Here is sample code:

```
import os
import multiprocessing

counter = 0


def analyze(file):
    # Analyze the file.
    global counter
    counter += 1
    print counter


if __name__ == '__main__':
    files = os.listdir('/some/directory')
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(4)
    pool.map(analyze, files)
```

I cannot find a solution for this.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

The problem is that the `counter` variable is not shared between your processes: each separate process is creating it's own local instance and incrementing that.

See [this section](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes) of the documentation for some techniques you can employ to share state between your processes.  In your case you might want to share a [`Value`](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Value) instance between your workers

Here's a working version of your example (with some dummy input data).  Note it uses global values which I would really try to avoid in practice:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, Value
from time import sleep

counter = None

def init(args):
    ''' store the counter for later use '''
    global counter
    counter = args

def analyze_data(args):
    ''' increment the global counter, do something with the input '''
    global counter
    # += operation is not atomic, so we need to get a lock:
    with counter.get_lock():
        counter.value += 1
    print counter.value
    return args * 10

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #inputs = os.listdir(some_directory)

    #
    # initialize a cross-process counter and the input lists
    #
    counter = Value('i', 0)
    inputs = [1, 2, 3, 4]

    #
    # create the pool of workers, ensuring each one receives the counter 
    # as it starts. 
    #
    p = Pool(initializer = init, initargs = (counter, ))
    i = p.map_async(analyze_data, inputs, chunksize = 1)
    i.wait()
    print i.get()
```

Comment: Great answer! I had the same problem in IronPython, and while multiprocessing.Value is not available you can do something similar with clr.Reference and System.Threading.Interlocked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255461/how-to-atomically-increment-a-static-member-in-ironpython/2314858#2314858

Comment: @jkp, how would you do it without the global variable? - I'm trying to use a class, but it is not as easy as it seems. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816958/cant-pickle-type-instancemethod-when-using-pythons-multiprocessing-pool-ma

Comment: Unfortunately, this example appears to be flawed, since `counter.value += 1` is not atomic between processes, so the value will be wrong if run long enough with a few processes

Comment: In line with what Eli said, a `Lock` must surround the `counter value += 1` statement. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1233222/python-multiprocessing-easy-way-to-implement-a-simple-counter

Comment: Note that it  should be `with counter.get_lock()`, not `with counter.value.get_lock():`

Comment: @jkp, as @Jinghao-shi said, `counter.value.get_lock()` will produce `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'get_lock'`

Comment: It's easier to just output a list of returns from each worker and then count the list after the fact

Answer (score 50):

Counter class without the race-condition bug:

```
class Counter(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.val = multiprocessing.Value('i', 0)

    def increment(self, n=1):
        with self.val.get_lock():
            self.val.value += n

    @property
    def value(self):
        return self.val.value
```

Comment: For similar code that works with `joblib`s `Parallel` (the code in this answer does not work with `joblib`), see https://github.com/davidheryanto/etc/blob/master/python-recipes/parallel-joblib-counter.py

Comment: I'd also add `return self` to the `increment` function to enable chaining

Comment: A similar answer includes the lock also in the value function and uses `RawValue` instead of `Value`. Do you think thst is needed? https://stackoverflow.com/a/35088457/469294

Answer (score 18):

A extremly simple example, changed from jkp's answer:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, Value
from time import sleep

counter = Value('i', 0)
def f(x):
    global counter
    with counter.get_lock():
        counter.value += 1
    print("counter.value:", counter.value)
    sleep(1)
    return x

with Pool(4) as p:
    r = p.map(f, range(1000*1000))
```

Comment: I tested your code. Counter is not shared. Each process has its own counter.

Answer (score 7):

Faster Counter class without using the built-in lock of Value twice

```
class Counter(object):
    def __init__(self, initval=0):
        self.val = multiprocessing.RawValue('i', initval)
        self.lock = multiprocessing.Lock()

    def increment(self):
        with self.lock:
            self.val.value += 1

    @property
    def value(self):
        return self.val.value
```

https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/01/04/shared-counter-with-pythons-multiprocessing
https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.sharedctypes.Value
https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.sharedctypes.RawValue

Comment: Basically the same with `Value` with `lock=True`, but this code is more clear.

Comment: A similar answer includes the lock also in the value function: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35088457/469294

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution to your problem based on a different approach from that proposed in the other answers. It uses *message passing* with `multiprocessing.Queue` objects (instead of *shared memory* with `multiprocessing.Value` objects) and process-safe (atomic) built-in increment and decrement operators `+=` and `-=` (instead of introducing custom `increment` and `decrement` methods) since you asked for it.

First, we define a class `Subject` for instantiating an object that will be local to the parent process and whose attributes are to be incremented or decremented:

```py
import multiprocessing


class Subject:

    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0
```

Next, we define a class `Proxy` for instantiating an object that will be the remote proxy through which the child processes will request the parent process to retrieve or update the attributes of the `Subject` object. The interprocess communication will use two `multiprocessing.Queue` attributes, one for exchanging requests and one for exchanging responses. Requests are of the form `(sender, action, *args)` where `sender` is the sender name, `action` is the action name (`'get'`, `'set'`, `'increment'`, or `'decrement'` the value of an attribute), and `args` is the argument tuple. Responses are of the form `value` (to `'get'` requests):

```py
class Proxy(Subject):

    def __init__(self, request_queue, response_queue):
        self.__request_queue = request_queue
        self.__response_queue = response_queue

    def _getter(self, target):
        sender = multiprocessing.current_process().name
        self.__request_queue.put((sender, 'get', target))
        return Decorator(self.__response_queue.get())

    def _setter(self, target, value):
        sender = multiprocessing.current_process().name
        action = getattr(value, 'action', 'set')
        self.__request_queue.put((sender, action, target, value))

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._getter('x')

    @property
    def y(self):
        return self._getter('y')

    @x.setter
    def x(self, value):
        self._setter('x', value)

    @y.setter
    def y(self, value):
        self._setter('y', value)
```

Then, we define the class `Decorator` to decorate the `int` objects returned by the getters of a `Proxy` object in order to inform its setters whether the increment or decrement operators `+=` and `-=` have been used by adding an `action` attribute, in which case the setters request an `'increment'` or `'decrement'` operation instead of a `'set'` operation. The increment and decrement operators `+=` and `-=` call the corresponding augmented assignment special methods `__iadd__` and `__isub__` if they are defined, and fall back on the assignment special methods `__add__` and `__sub__` which are always defined for `int` objects (e.g. `proxy.x += value` is equivalent to `proxy.x = proxy.x.__iadd__(value)` which is equivalent to `proxy.x = type(proxy).x.__get__(proxy).__iadd__(value)` which is equivalent to `type(proxy).x.__set__(proxy, type(proxy).x.__get__(proxy).__iadd__(value))`):

```py
class Decorator(int):

    def __iadd__(self, other):
        value = Decorator(other)
        value.action = 'increment'
        return value

    def __isub__(self, other):
        value = Decorator(other)
        value.action = 'decrement'
        return value
```

Then, we define the function `worker` that will be run in the child processes and request the increment and decrement operations:

```py
def worker(proxy):
    proxy.x += 1
    proxy.y -= 1
```

Finally, we define a single request queue to send requests to the parent process, and multiple response queues to send responses to the child processes:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    subject = Subject()
    request_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
    response_queues = {}
    processes = []
    for index in range(4):
        sender = 'child {}'.format(index)
        response_queues[sender] = multiprocessing.Queue()
        proxy = Proxy(request_queue, response_queues[sender])
        process = multiprocessing.Process(
            target=worker, args=(proxy,), name=sender)
        processes.append(process)
    running = len(processes)
    for process in processes:
        process.start()
    while subject.x != 4 or subject.y != -4:
        sender, action, *args = request_queue.get()
        print(sender, 'requested', action, *args)
        if action == 'get':
            response_queues[sender].put(getattr(subject, args[0]))
        elif action == 'set':
            setattr(subject, args[0], args[1])
        elif action == 'increment':
            setattr(subject, args[0], getattr(subject, args[0]) + args[1])
        elif action == 'decrement':
            setattr(subject, args[0], getattr(subject, args[0]) - args[1])
    for process in processes:
        process.join()
```

The program is guaranteed to terminate when `+=` and `-=` are process-safe. If you remove process-safety by commenting the corresponding `__iadd__` or `__isub__` of `Decorator` then the program will only terminate by chance (e.g. `proxy.x += value` is equivalent to `proxy.x = proxy.x.__iadd__(value)` but falls back to `proxy.x = proxy.x.__add__(value)` if `__iadd__` is not defined, which is equivalent to `proxy.x = proxy.x + value` which is equivalent to `proxy.x = type(proxy).x.__get__(proxy) + value` which is equivalent to `type(proxy).x.__set__(proxy, type(proxy).x.__get__(proxy) + value)`, so the `action` attribute is not added and the setter requests a `'set'` operation instead of an `'increment'` operation).

Example process-safe session (atomic `+=` and `-=`):

```
child 0 requested get x
child 0 requested increment x 1
child 0 requested get y
child 0 requested decrement y 1
child 3 requested get x
child 3 requested increment x 1
child 3 requested get y
child 2 requested get x
child 3 requested decrement y 1
child 1 requested get x
child 2 requested increment x 1
child 2 requested get y
child 2 requested decrement y 1
child 1 requested increment x 1
child 1 requested get y
child 1 requested decrement y 1
```

Example process-unsafe session (non-atomic `+=` and `-=`):

```
child 2 requested get x
child 1 requested get x
child 0 requested get x
child 2 requested set x 1
child 2 requested get y
child 1 requested set x 1
child 1 requested get y
child 2 requested set y -1
child 1 requested set y -1
child 0 requested set x 1
child 0 requested get y
child 0 requested set y -2
child 3 requested get x
child 3 requested set x 2
child 3 requested get y
child 3 requested set y -3  # the program stalls here
```

Answer (score 0):

A more sophisticated solution based on the lock-free atomic operations, as given by example on [atomics library README](https://github.com/doodspav/atomics#multi-processing):

```py
from multiprocessing import Process, shared_memory

import atomics


def fn(shmem_name: str, width: int, n: int) -> None:
    shmem = shared_memory.SharedMemory(name=shmem_name)
    buf = shmem.buf[:width]
    with atomics.atomicview(buffer=buf, atype=atomics.INT) as a:
        for _ in range(n):
            a.inc()
    del buf
    shmem.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # setup
    width = 4
    shmem = shared_memory.SharedMemory(create=True, size=width)
    buf = shmem.buf[:width]
    total = 10_000
    # run processes to completion
    p1 = Process(target=fn, args=(shmem.name, width, total // 2))
    p2 = Process(target=fn, args=(shmem.name, width, total // 2))
    p1.start(), p2.start()
    p1.join(), p2.join()
    # print results and cleanup
    with atomics.atomicview(buffer=buf, atype=atomics.INT) as a:
        print(f"a[{a.load()}] == total[{total}]")
    del buf
    shmem.close()
    shmem.unlink()
```

(atomics could be [installed](https://github.com/doodspav/atomics#installing) via `pip install atomics` on most of the major platforms)

Answer (score -1):

I'm working on a process bar in PyQT5, so I use thread and pool together

```
import threading
import multiprocessing as mp
from queue import Queue

def multi(x):
    return x*x

def pooler(q):
    with mp.Pool() as pool:
    count = 0
    for i in pool.imap_unordered(ggg, range(100)):
        print(count, i)
        count += 1
        q.put(count)

def main():
    q = Queue()
    t = threading.Thread(target=thr, args=(q,))
    t.start()
    print('start')
    process = 0
    while process < 100:
        process = q.get()
        print('p',process)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

this I put in Qthread worker and it works with acceptable latency

Answer (score -1):

This is a different solution and the simplest to my taste.
The reasoning is you create an empty list and append to it each time your function executes , then print len(list) to check progress.

Here is an example based on your code :

```
import os
import multiprocessing
counter = []


def analyze(file):
    # Analyze the file.
    counter.append(' ')
    print len(counter)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    files = os.listdir('/some/directory')
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(4)
    pool.map(analyze, files)
```

Add counter to multiprocessing as follow :

```
    from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

    counter = []

    def your_function():
       # function/process
       counter.append(' ') # you can append anything
       return len(counter)

    pool = ThreadPool()
    result = pool.map(get_data, urls)
```

Comment: Python lists are not process safe and they consume too much memory if we want to count a really big number

Comment: You're assuming that OP has an issue with memory consumption on hardware rather than finding a solution ?