# Collecting IronPython Parallel Loop results

Tags: python, .net, task-parallel-library, ironpython, parallel.foreach

I am trying to get a result from the tasks method in IronPython similar to how `results.get` works with CPython `multiprocessing.Queue`

```
from System.Threading.Tasks import *
def testThread(dataPnt,constData):
    return dataPnt

def main():

    dataToSplit = range(5)
    constData = 10

    threadResult = Parallel.ForEach(dataToSplit, lambda dataPnt: testThread(dataPnt,constData))

    print(threadResult)

main()
```

At this point threadResult is `System.Threading.Tasks.ParallelLoopResult` but I can't find any decent documentation.  The closest has been [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255461/how-to-atomically-increment-a-static-member-in-ironpython/2314858#2314858) but it is incrementing and I need an array returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Parallel.ForEach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach?view=netframework-4.8) is a multi-processing operation but given that you expect a result from your operation you would either have to use a shared result variable (e.g. some sort of [concurrent collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent?view=netframework-4.8)) or use a [parallel LINQ projection operation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/parallel-linq-plinq).

An approach close to your sample could look like:

```
# get LINQ dependencies
import clr
clr.AddReference("System.Core")
import System
clr.ImportExtensions(System.Linq)

from System.Threading.Tasks import *
def testThread(dataPnt,constData):
    print dataPnt
    return dataPnt

def main():

    dataToSplit = range(5)
    constData = 10

    threadResult = dataToSplit.AsParallel().Select(lambda dataPnt: testThread(dataPnt,constData)).ToList()

    print(threadResult)

main()
```