# Python multiprocessing - shared counter in global list is not incrementing properly

Tags: python, global-variables, multiprocessing

I am trying to implement a shared counter in multiprocessing. I am using a global variable to get around pickling problems. For reasons I do not understand, the increment does not seem to apply on my global counter list (the value is always 0). I guess it the code is using a local instance of the variable that gets discarded.

I thought that global lists can be modified, because they are mutable. I also tried explicitly defining `global list_global` to specify that I want to use the global definition of the variable.

Can someone please point out my error?

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, Value, Lock

list_global = [] # global variable to hold Counter values


#http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/01/04/shared-counter-with-pythons-multiprocessing/
class Counter(object):    
    def __init__(self, initval=0):
        self.val = Value('i', initval)
        self.lock = Lock()
##        self.val = initval

    def increment(self):
        with self.lock:
            self.val.value += 1

    def value(self):
        with self.lock:
            return self.val.value


def process_item(x):
    global list_global
    list_global[0].increment()     # increments
    return list_global[0].value()  # correctly returns incremented value


def main():
    global list_global

    print 'before', list_global[0].value()

    pool = Pool()
    print pool.map(process_item, range(10))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    #increments in process_item are not persistent
    #(do not appear to be modifying the global variable)
    print 'after', list_global[0].value()  #=> 0


# list_global holds 3 Counter objects
for i in range(3):
    list_global.append(Counter(0))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    global list_global
    main()
    #print list_global # list_global holds "Counter" objects
    for i in list_global:
        print i.value(), #=>[0,0,0] # expected [10,0,0]
```

Comment: You're not "working around" pickling problems by using a global variable.  That's not how it's done.  Your current implementation is flawed.

Comment: You *really* wasn't able to find the question [Python multiprocessing and a shared counter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2080660/python-multiprocessing-and-a-shared-counter), not even when typing the title of your question? (it pops up as first result...) Please, *search* before asking a question.

Comment: @Bakuriu - I had seen that example. I thought my implementation was different because I used shared memory `Value` objects. This did not work out as I had hoped, but it was not so obvious to me (before asking) that the answer was a duplicate. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More specific than my comment, your problem is that you're fundamentally misunderstanding what multiprocessing is doing, which produces faulty expectations for your output.  You can't declare a global variable and then share it across multiple processes.  You can get away with a little bit more when you use Threads, but in order to understand why you're having trouble, you need to realize what multiprocessing is *doing*.

When `Pool.map()` fires up your child processes, each of them launches *its own* python interpreter where it imports your top level function `process_item`.  This separate interpreter instance also creates *its own* instance of `list_global`.  That happens for *every* child process.  Your calls to `global` don't just magically make those separate running processes share a list defined in your module.

Comment: very interesting. Thanks for taking the time to explain. Obviously, I have some more reading to do.