# Python - Global counter

Tags: python

I am recursively generating few objects, which need a contiguous, unique id. How can I guarantee (easiest) the synchronization in python 2.7.

```
iid = 1

def next_id():
    iid += 1
    return iid

def process():
    # .. do something
    id = next_id()
```

Comment: Are you talking about synchronization as in shared memory concurrency?

Comment: I am not sure about threading model, whether recursive calls involve multiple threads in python. To make sure access (read and update counter) to the counter as in the example is protected, I was looking for a mutex like sync primitive. Not sure how to do it python. Indeed, I am not sure whether it is needed for recursive function calls. In this case the counter would be accessed from the recursive calls, but not sure whether will be concurrent.

Comment: Function calls, whether recursive or not, involve neither parallelism or concurrency. If you don't explicitly create a `threading.Thread` object, or call other code that has "launched threads" written all over it, you are single-threaded and neither need to nor should synchronize.

Comment: @bsreekanth:  Recursive calls do not use multiple threads in python, so you do not need synchronization.  The simplest approach is [given](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12480131/1322401) by glglgl below.  Set `iid = itertools.count(starting_id)`.  Then call `next(iid)` for each new id you need.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use a [mutex](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#lock-objects):

```
import threading
iid = 1
iid_lock = threading.Lock()

def next_id():
    global iid
    with iid_lock:
        result = iid
        iid += 1
    return result
```

You might like to hide the internals in a class:

```
class IdGenerator(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.cur_id = 1
        self.lock = threading.Lock()
    def next_id(self):
        with self.lock:
            result = self.cur_id
            self.cur_id += 1
        return result
```

EDIT: Based on the comments, it seems like you're not using threads. This means you don't need the locking mechanism at all. What you initially wrote would be sufficient, though you need the `global` keyword to make the global variable mutable:

```
iid = 1
def next_id():
    global iid
    res = iid
    iid += 1
    return res
```

Comment: If you define `__iter__` and `next()` on that class, it will work with the iterator protocol, which might be convenient (e.g. allowing you to write `next(id)` if `id` is an instance of that class).

Comment: -1.  The OP does not need synchronizaton.  The OP mistakenly thought that recursion might be implemented with multiple threads in Python.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: oh, good catch. deleting my answer. (EDIT: oops it is accepted now... will modify it then)

Comment: Removing my downvote in light of the correction.  I still prefer glglgl's simpler answer, which uses a global `itertools.count` iterator.

Comment: fair, i was considering just putting his in mine for that reason. it is a bit more elegant

Comment: regardless of the ops intention, this is the first hit when searching for "python synchronized counter", so this answer is useful.  Maybe it just needs to be tied to a new question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1233222/python-multiprocessing-easy-way-to-implement-a-simple-counter is probably a better match to searching for "python synchronized counter"

Answer (score 19):

```
from itertools import count
iid = count()

print next(iid) # 0
print next(iid) # 1
print next(iid) # 2
```

etc., and

```
new_iid = count(10)
print next(new_iid) # 10
print next(new_iid) # 11
print next(new_iid) # 12
```

for starting at other values than 0.

`count()` is essentially a generator which infinitely yields values.

Comment: @Claudiu Read the comments on the question, it does not need to be.

Answer (score 0):

You were thinking to something of this kind:

```
 class Counter():
    def __init__(self):
        self.theCount = -1 
    def __call__(self):
        self.theCount += 1
        return self.theCount 

class BorgCounter():
    Borg = {'theCount':-1} 
    def __init__(self):
        self.__dict__ = BorgCounter.Borg 
    def __call__(self):
        self.theCount += 1
        return self.theCount 

myCount = Counter() 
mycount2 = Counter() 
assert(myCount()==0)
assert(mycount2()==0)
assert(mycount2()==1)
assert(myCount()==1)
assert(myCount()==2)

myCount = BorgCounter() 
mycount2 = BorgCounter() 
assert(myCount()==0)
assert(mycount2()==1)
assert(mycount2()==2)
assert(myCount()==3)
assert(myCount()==4)
```