# Python3 multiprocessing shared object

Tags: python, multiprocessing, shared-memory, python-3.2

I stumbled across a synchronization issue for a shared object when using the `multiprocessing` module in Python 3.2.3 (on Debian 7.5). I put together this simple example to illustrate the problem, its functionality is similar to `multiprocessing.Pool.map` (the simplest I could think of). I am using a `multiprocessing.Manager` since my original code uses it (sync'ing over network). But the behavior is the same if I use a simple `multiprocessing.Value` for the counter variable.

```
import os as os
import sys as sys
import multiprocessing as mp

def mp_map(function, obj_list, num_workers):
    """ 
    """
    mang = mp.Manager()
    jobq = mang.Queue()
    resq = mang.Queue()
    counter = mp.Value('i', num_workers, lock=True)
    finished = mang.Event()
    processes = []
    try:
        for i in range(num_workers):
            p = mp.Process(target=_parallel_execute, kwargs={'execfun':function, 'jobq':jobq, 'resq':resq, 'counter':counter, 'finished':finished})
            p.start()
            p.join(0)
            processes.append(p)
        for item in obj_list:
            jobq.put(item)
        for i in range(len(processes)):
            jobq.put('SENTINEL')
        finished.wait()
        for p in processes:
            if p.is_alive():
                p.join(1)
                p.terminate()
    except Exception as e:
        for p in processes:
            p.terminate()
        raise e
    results = []
    for item in iter(resq.get, 'DONE'):
        results.append(item)
    return results

def _parallel_execute(execfun, jobq, resq, counter, finished):
    """
    """
    for item in iter(jobq.get, 'SENTINEL'):
        item = execfun(item)
        resq.put(item)
    counter.value -= 1
    print('C: {}'.format(counter.value))
    if counter.value <= 0:
        resq.put('DONE')
        finished.set()
    return


if __name__ == '__main__':
    l = list(range(50))
    l = mp_map(id, l, 2)
    print('done')
    sys.exit(0)
```

Running the above code for a couple of times leads to the following:

```
wks:~$ python3 mpmap.py 
C: 1
C: 0
done
wks:~$ python3 mpmap.py 
C: 1
C: 0
done
wks:~$ python3 mpmap.py 
C: 1
C: 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mpmap.py", line 55, in <module>
    l = mp_map(id, l, 2)
  File "mpmap.py", line 25, in mp_map
    finished.wait()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 1013, in wait
    return self._callmethod('wait', (timeout,))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 762, in _callmethod
    kind, result = conn.recv()
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Based on the documentation of the `multiprocessing` module, I do not see why the `counter` is not process safe, as the access to it is managed via the `Manager` and it is clearly initialized with `lock=True`. Since the deadlock only happens every now and then, I am not really sure how to interpret this behavior. Any helpful insights are very much appreciated, thanks.

**EDIT:**
It just happens that I found an explanation after googling a little more; I will share that here if somebody else is interested: based on this blog entry [1](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/01/04/shared-counter-with-pythons-multiprocessing/) linked below, the locking done in Python (i.e. in `multiprocessing.[Manager].Value` with `lock=True`) does not lead to atomic operations on shared values like in the example. The solution is to use another lock shared among the processes that is used to control access to the shared objects.

[http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/01/04/shared-counter-with-pythons-multiprocessing/]

Comment: `counter.value -= 1` isn't atomic despite `lock=True`. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1233363/3826372

Comment: Thanks for the remark and the link; however, found the answer by googling more (see my edit)

Comment: Yes, I know. You made that edit at the same time I made my comment. In any case, you shouldn't answer your own questions by editing the question. You should post an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As advised by Ross, I repeat the answer here:
Briefly, `lock=True` for `multiprocessing.Value` or `multiprocessing.Manager.Value` does not make e.g. an increment (decrement) of the value an atomic operation - a separate lock is needed to encapsulate the entire operation; for a code example, see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/1233363/3826372 or the aforementioned blog entry http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/01/04/shared-counter-with-pythons-multiprocessing